# How to fetch google sign-in script in ionic app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, google-apps-script, ionic-framework

Here is my problem. I am trying to add to my `ionic` app a possibility to sign in with google account. Everything works just fine in chrome, but when I installed the app on a device, it turned out that there is a problem with fetching the google's sing-in script. I get **403** response.

Here is the function that loads it:

```
loadGoogleScript(login = false): void {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
    script.onload = () => {
      if (!login) {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: oauthClientId,
          callback: this.registerWithGoogle,
          context: 'signup',
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById('googleButton'),
          { theme: 'outline', size: 'large', text: 'signup_with' }
        );
      } else {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: oauthClientId,
          callback: this.loginWithGoogle,
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById('loginGoogleButton'),
          { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' }
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
      }
    };
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

At first, I thought the problem could be the wrong configuration of `OAuth 2.0` client identifier.
I set the package name to the name `applicationId` from `build.gradle` file, and `SHA-1` as the key from `debug.keystore`. I did not work to I tried to generate a release keystore. Did not work too.

Comment: you should not be calling createElement to assign script. Google has great examples in the docs on how to do what you need.

Comment: try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth